# Временно изменить переменную

Tags: c#, c++

Приведу пример:

`k = i++ +i` даст `k = 2*i` и затем увеличит `i`.

`k = ++i +i` увеличит `i`, затем даст `k = 2*i+1`.

Мне же нужно положить в `k` на 1 больше, чем `i`, но сам `i` не менять.

Есть ли в `c++/c#` что-то такое, что было бы короче, чем: `k = i + 1`?
И аналогично с минусом. Или не короче, но без самого знака "1".

Comment: Вы, конечно, знаете, что `i++ + i` в C++ есть undefined behaviour, да?

Comment: А в C# `i++ + i` гарантировано даёт результат `2*i + 1`.

Comment: _"`k = i++ +i` даст `k = 2*i` и затем увеличит `i`"_ - это неправда: http://ideone.com/GhmfM0

Comment: @VladD, пока я делал пример, ты меня опередил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy: У меня была открыта Студия :)

Comment: @VladD, я и так знал, что 21. Но надо было дать на что-то ссылку))

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я помнил, что результат детерминистический, но не помнил, какой именно :)

Comment: @VladD, а зачем там помнить? В шарпе всё просто: слева направо.

Comment: вопрос был именно по функции, которая давала бы на 1 меньше/больше. пусть будет i+ i++ и i+ ++i, кроме того я обычно скобками всё обильно поливаю, чтобы не париться с приоритетами.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин: Скобки не помогут, в C++ в любом случае UB.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну почти всегда слева направо: http://ideone.com/76VRPZ (хотя, возможно, это баг).

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Скобки тут ничего не дадут. Ваш код бессмыслен с точки зрения С++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Короче** чем `i + 1` в языках C++ и C# для операции «получить на единицу большее значение» ничего нет.

Но вы легко можете выкатить свою функцию:

```
int next(int i) { return i + 1; }
```

и пользоваться ей.

(В C# нету свободных функций, так что вам может быть ещё понадобится [`using static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#using-static).)

Заметьте, что `next(i)` никак не короче, чем `i+1`: одни только скобки добавляют два символа, а ещё имя функции должно содержать как минимум один символ.

---

Кстати, в Паскале нужная вам функция есть: [`Succ`](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Succ.html).

Comment: succ именно то, что нужно. жаль, что в С-подобных её нет. было бы удобно по аналогии с i++ (например iππ), но вместо плюса другой знак использовать. настроить ввод такого знака не проблема. а вот как это всё заставить работать правильно -- вот задача.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин новые операторы в C# создавать нельзя. Можно менять поведение существующих операторов, и то не всех.

Comment: @rdorn что именно служит ограничителем? пусть не через код проекта (.cpp или .cs), а настройки среды разработки такое возможно? или всё упирается в компилятор?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин разумеется в компилятор. Операторы и их знаки это часть синтаксиса языка.

Answer (score -1):

```
int i = 2;
int k;
(k = i)++;//k == 3
```